# Search an arraylist without loop in java

Tags: java, loops

Is there any way to search an `ArrayList` in *Java* without using a loop since I have lots of collections to search, and it takes long time to search using loops.

Comment: You can either do the looping yourself, or use _ArrayList.contains()_ (which will just use a loop internally).  Or (if possible) you can use a Map (as @SLaks has mentioned).

Comment: ivanovic: loops takes time; in addition, I have to write long code fragments

Comment: SLaks: There is a problem with hashing that I can't get the index of the element

Answer (score 5):

If you keep your lists sorted, you can search them significantly faster using

```
Collections.binarySearch(array, key);
```

in your favorite [java.util.Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class.

Otherwise, you might want to look into TreeSet and HashSet.

But maybe you can improve your overall algorithm? Or build an **index**?

Answer (score 2):

If the elements of your array list are not arranged in any particular order, then you *have* to loop over the list in one way or another.

If the array list does not change, one possibility might be to pre-sort it and then repeatedly use [binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29).

Otherwise you'll need to employ a different data structure, such as a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).